# Java Auto Boxing and conditional operator

Tags: java, sonarqube, autoboxing

In sonar i see a major violation warning for code

```
  public Long getValue(FieldType fieldType) {
    Long value = paramLevelMap.get(fieldType); // ok returns Long not long
    return value == null ? UNSPECIFIED_PARAMETER_KEY : value; // complaints here
  }
```

Where 'UNSPECIFIED_PARAMETER_KEY' is pvt static long , and 'value' is also long.

> Boxed value is unboxed and then immediately reboxed

Its complaining on the 2nd line. I didn't quite understand it , when & how is primitive long being converted to corresponding class object ? and back ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return type of a ternary (or more correctly, *conditional*) expression where the second and third operands consist of one primitive and one corresponding boxed version, is that of the primitive.
(For a complete analysis of the type of the conditional operator, look at [the Java Specifications 15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).)

Since the second operand here, `UNSPECIFIED_PARAMETER_KEY`, is a `long`, and the third, `value` is a `Long`, Java has to unbox `value` to a `long` to evaluate the expression.

After this, a `Long` is to be returned, so `value` is immediately reboxed.

You can fix this by changing your constant `UNSPECIFIED_PARAMETER_KEY` into a `Long`.